# How to connect to my centos server's desktop?

Tags: linux, centos, vncserver

My centos server was startup to command line mode (console), and I install desktop on that server.
after that I set up vncserver from putty, and connect to it using vncviewer, but I can not get into the desktop environment in installed but xwindow desktop instead, and if I try to "startx" in the vncviewer, error occurs, what's wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

startkde works......